# Ytick values are all messed up when plotting a column from a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

One of columns in a dataframe has null values. It shows Gini index from year 1991 to 2020 but only following years have some values.
1993 : 31.70,
2004: 34.4,
2009: 35.4,
2011: 35.7,
2015: 34.70,
2016:34.80,
2017:35.90,
2018: 34.60,
2019:35.70.
Rest of the years between 1991 and 2020 has null values. I am using following code to plot a bar graph. But all the ytick values are messed up. Those values start from 31.70 and end at 34.60 and all the values in between are not in particular order.

```
final_df=final_df.replace('..','')
final_df1=final_df.dropna(subset=['Gini index'])
ax4.bar(final_df1['Year'],final_df1['Gini index'])
```

I tried using following code to get ytick values however it does not work

```
yticks = ax4.get_yticks()
ax4.set_yticklabels(['{:.1f}'.format(y) for y in yticks])
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have any data to show to see the structure of your dataframe?

Comment: The problem could be that the `final_df1['Gini index']` is a string column, not int or float. Check before you plot using `print(final_df1.info)`

Answer (score 0):

A vertical bar chart takes `y` values as the `height` of the plot. Since there are missing values, the plot cannot assign a value to `height`, so it returns an error. You should replace the missing values with 0. I don't have your data, so made it up myself.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
years = list(range(1991, 2020))
vals = [7, 7, 15, "", 20, 5, 13, 9, "", 13, 6, 4, "", 6, 1, "", 17, 7, "", 20, 15, 1, 6, 16, 20, 20, "", 5, 11]

df.head(10)
```

[image]

```
# Replace empty cells with 0
df["values"] = df["values"].replace('', 0)

# Plot
plt.bar(df["year"], df["values"], color ='maroon', width = 0.4)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]